# How to get the last row of each name?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I extract the unique names with the latest end date from the following table using Oracle sql.

```
NAME    Start DATE  End Date
ATO210291676    21/11/2015  18/05/2016
ATO210291676    19/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210291889    21/11/2015  18/05/2016
ATO210291889    19/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210291923    21/11/2015  18/05/2016
ATO210291923    19/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210186276    25/05/2015  24/05/2016
ATO210186276    25/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210186373    25/05/2015  24/05/2016
ATO210186373    25/05/2016  30/06/2017
TNT212498119    29/06/2015  28/06/2016
TNT212498119    29/06/2016  30/06/2017
TNT212498349    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212491256    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212502235    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212522556    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212522582    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
CVE114AK0076    16/09/2015  26/06/2016
CVE114AK0076    27/06/2016  30/06/2017
CVE414AK0012    15/09/2015  26/06/2016
CVE414AK0012    27/06/2016  30/06/2017
```

---

I am trying to produce the following result.

```html
ATO210291676    19/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210291889    19/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210291923    19/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210186276    25/05/2016  30/06/2017
ATO210186373    25/05/2016  30/06/2017
TNT212498119    29/06/2016  30/06/2017
TNT212498349    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212491256    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212502235    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212522556    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
ATO212522582    26/02/2016  30/06/2017
CVE114AK0076    27/06/2016  30/06/2017
CVE414AK0012    27/06/2016  30/06/2017
```

The resultset should be like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select      NAME
           ,"Start DATE"
           ,"End Date"           

from       (select      t.*
                       ,row_number () over (partition by NAME order by "End Date" desc) as rn

            from        t
            ) t

where       rn = 1
;
```

Comment: @DilanPerera,  P.s. if you liked the answer you might want to upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, MAX(ENDDate)
from tab
GROUP BY NAME
```

You can use `max` function to get the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, StartDate, EndDate
FROM [Your_Table] A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Name, MAX(EndDate) AS MaxEndDate
    FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
    GROUP BY Name
) B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.EndDate = B.EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result in one pass, without joins or subqueries. Whether this leads to a speed improvement is for you to determine, by trying the different solutions on your actual data.

```
select   name, 
         max(start_date) keep (dense_rank last order by end_date) as start_date, 
         max(end_date) as end_date
from     table_name
group by name
;
```